# How do I strikethrough in \text{} inside inline math mode

Tags: amsmath, text-decorations, strikeout

I want to strike out the word "prime" in the given below text. How can I do it?

```
$\mathfrak{P}:=\{\text{set of all prime ideals contained in} \ A\setminus S\}$.
```

Comment: Welcome  to the site! You mean strike, by the way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `\sout` command from `ulem`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath} % These fonts are just examples.
\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}
$\mathfrak{P}:={\textnormal{set of all \sout{prime} ideals contained in} \ A\setminus S}$
\end{document}
```

[image: newpx sample]

You usually want `\textnormal`, rather than `\text`, so that the formatting of the surrounding text will not bleed through.

Comment: Can I use this in math.stackexchange as well? I tried using this, it did not work.

Comment: Ah, I'm scarce in English language. Hence the OP want to cut the word :-(

Comment: @Saikat I don’t think it works in MathJax.

Comment: @Saikat Some versions of MathJax support `\cancel{prime}`. You could give it a try.

Comment: It is not working with \cancel{prime}

Comment: @Saikat Well, MathJax is different, and all I can suggest is that you check the documentation. You might need to find some alternative.

Comment: You can use in MathJaX You can use in MathJax `\require{enclose}, \enclose{horizontalstrike}{prime}`.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks!